# Javascript defining method using this V/s prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

In Object-oriented Javascript, we can define a method inside an object as

```
this.myMethod = function() {

}
```

OR

we can use the prototype way

```
MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function() {

}
```

What are the differences between the 2 techniques ?

Comment: In the former, every instance of your object will carry their own copies of member functions.

Answer (score 1):

First:

```
function Person(name){
    this.name = name
    this.sayHi = function(){
        return 'Hi, I am ' + this.name
    }
}
```

Second:

```
function Person(name){
    this.name = name
}
Person.prototype.sayHi = function(){
    return 'Hi, I am ' + this.name
}
```

In the first version, each time you create a person, a new sayHi function will be created for him, where as in the second version, only one sayHi function is ever created, and is shared amongst all persons that are created - because Person.prototype is their parent. Thus, declaring methods on the prototype is more memory efficient.

Source:
http://tobyho.com/2010/11/22/javascript-constructors-and/

Comment: Is the first version `this.sayHi` what Douglas Crockford calls privileged method?

Comment: @Stack0verflow: Yes it is, because it would be privileged to access the constructor's local `name` *variable* directly (not only the "public" `.name` property)